# Control flicker while dragging in run time

Tags: c#, button, tabs, drag, flicker

Stack Overflow users. In a C# VS 2010 Windows Form project I have a problem regarding control flicker when dragging a user created control around on a tab page during run time. I used the following code:

```
private void control_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)         
{              
    if (isDragged)             
    {                 
        Point newPoint = ((Control)sender).PointToScreen(new Point(e.X, 
        e.Y));                 
        newPoint.Offset(ptOffset);                 
        ((Control)sender).Location = newPoint;                 
        ((Control)sender).Refresh();             
    }         
}          
private void control_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)         
{                           
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)             
    {                 
        isDragged = true;                 
        Point ptStartPosition = ((Control)sender).PointToScreen(new 
        Point(e.X, e.Y));                  
        ptOffset = new Point();                 
        ptOffset.X = ((Control)sender).Location.X - ptStartPosition.X;                 
        ptOffset.Y = ((Control)sender).Location.Y - ptStartPosition.Y;             
    }             
    else             
    {                 
        isDragged = false;             
    }          
}          
private void control_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)         
{             
    ((Control)sender).Refresh();             
    isDragged = false;         
}
private void createButton_PB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int ctrlExists = 0;
    string btnName = btnName_TB.Text;

    foreach (Button button in tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls)
    {
        if (button.Text == btnName)
        {
            ctrlExists = 1;
        }
    }
    if (btnName_TB.Text != "" && ctrlExists == 0)
    {               
        Button newButton = new Button();
        newButton.Name = btnName.Replace(" ", String.Empty);
        newButton.Name += "u";
        newButton.Text = btnName;
        tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Add(newButton);
        newButton.Left = 10;
        newButton.Top = 420;  
        lastBtnClicked = newButton;
    }
    SetupClickEvents(tabControl1.SelectedTab);
}
```

So, the problem is that I can add a button and drag it around in run time. But, when I add another Button and drag it around...after I've done that, and go back to trying to drag the first button, that button flickers and acts as if it is trying to move all over the place. Sometimes it disappears. I feel like this has something to do with the fact that the controls are inside a tab page. Perhaps I am not properly calculating the "newPoint" variable. Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found a few fundamental flaws related to the button creation and the events that were being added at the time of creation. I made some considerable changes and the issue seems to have gone away. Following is the updated code.

```
    private void control_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    { 
        if (isDragged)
        {
            Point newPoint = ((Control)sender).PointToScreen(new Point(e.X, 
            e.Y));
            newPoint.Offset(ptOffset);
            ((Control)sender).Location = newPoint;
            ((Control)sender).Refresh();
        }
    }

    private void control_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            isDragged = true;

            ((Control)sender).MouseMove += new 
            MouseEventHandler(control_MouseMove);

            Point ptStartPosition = ((Control)sender).PointToScreen(new 
            Point(e.X, e.Y));

            ptOffset = new Point();
            ptOffset.X = ((Control)sender).Location.X - ptStartPosition.X;
            ptOffset.Y = ((Control)sender).Location.Y - ptStartPosition.Y;
        }
        else
        {
            isDragged = false;
        }

    }

    private void control_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        ((Control)sender).MouseMove -= control_MouseMove;
        ((Control)sender).Refresh();
        isDragged = false;
    }

    private void SetupClickEvents(Control control)
    {            
        control.Click += new EventHandler(StoreLastClick);
        control.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(control_MouseDown);
        //control.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(control_MouseMove);
        control.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(control_MouseUp);            
    }



    private void createButton_PB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ctrlExists = 0;
        string btnName = btnName_TB.Text;

        foreach (Button button in tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls)
        {
            if (button.Name == btnName)
            {
                ctrlExists = 1;
            }
        }
        if (btnName_TB.Text != "" && ctrlExists == 0)
        {               
            Button newButton = new Button();
            newButton.Name = btnName.Replace(" ", String.Empty);
            newButton.Text = btnName;
            tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Add(newButton);
            newButton.Left = 10;
            newButton.Top = 420;
            SetupClickEvents(newButton);
        }
    }

    private void deleteButton_PB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ctrlExists = 0;

        if (lastCtrlClicked != null)
        {
            string btnName = lastCtrlClicked.Name;
            foreach (Button button in tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls)
            {
                if (button.Name == btnName)
                {
                    ctrlExists = 1;
                }
            }
        }

        if (ctrlExists == 1 && lastCtrlClicked != null)
        {
            tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Remove(lastCtrlClicked);
            lastCtrlClicked.Dispose();
            ctrlExists = 0;
        }
        lastCtrlClicked = null;
    }
```